# Multi-select pick list update - process builder + apex or flow?

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow

I want to update a multi-select picklist to remove one particular value given certain conditions on update.

At the moment the condition is detected by process builder, but I'm unable to update the field from within process builder, because you can't use formula + Substitute function to remove the value.

So, I either have to do this through a flow or by calling some apex code.

Which would be the preferred approach? Is it just a matter of personal taste, or is there any good reason to use one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The best choice to do it will be Before update trigger.
Reason:-

1. You are going to update the same record via process builder which increases processing time as triggers, workflow rules, process builders, etc executes once again.
2. Increased chances of 101 SOQL Limit error as same queries in trigger will run twice.
3. Before update trigger will be more useful in your use case as you have already stated that process builder is not suitable for your use case.

I use process builder only when I have to update/create other object records or call some asynchronous methods or platform events.